# Hide image source on HTML using PHP

Tags: php, html, image

In order to hide my images directory, so that the user doesn't know where the images are stored, how can I implement something like this?

```
<img src="https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/0/AADkpdIqLbXdAFgmjGbdsKa_InYsOtfwuekNtOyuHgmh3g/10/5642407/jpeg/32x32/6/_/1/2/Pensive%20Parakeet.jpg/HM183nQwcIFtc1PrTIOCRe4rIUK8wBaWKcgqD-g2Ma8?size=32bf&amp;prep_size=1280x960" draggable="true" alt="Pensive Parakeet.jpg" class="sprite sprite_web s_web_page_white_picture_32 icon thumbnail">
```

Where the source:
https://photos-1.dropbox.com/t/0/AADkpdIqLbXdAFgmjGbdsKa_InYsOtfwuekNtOyuHgmh3g/10/5642407/jpeg/32x32/6/_/1/2/Pensive%20Parakeet.jpg/HM183nQwcIFtc1PrTIOCRe4rIUK8wBaWKcgqD-g2Ma8?size=32bf&prep_size=1280x960

renders the image without any problem.

Comment: What is your reasoning behind hiding the image directory? If you use random ID strings for image names like Dropbox does, nobody should be able to snoop around in it

Comment: you can use background-image texhnique, but if the user is clever then he/she will finally get it ^^

Comment: You could use a php script as your image source and have the script return an image content type. The pathing would be considerably hidden.

Answer (score 1):

This type of functionality is typically implemented via a RewriteRule in your vhost or .htaccess file and some sort of image processing function.  For example, you can put something like this in an .htaccess file in, say, the /t directory off of your document root:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

This will transparently redirect all calls behind the scenes to, for example (if placed in your /t directory), `/t/0/foo/bar/stuff` to `/t/index.php/0/foo/bar/stuff`. Assuming you have an index.php file in that directory, you can then process all of the stuff in the URL it gets by parsing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` to figure out exactly what to return.

If you have images saved in an alternate location, you can return them by doing whatever munging you want to do with them and pushing them out to the browser using `imagepng()` or `imagejpg()`.  [See the example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) on one of those pages for how to do this.